# adjunctions between FinCat and Set

Tags: category-theory

I am looking for an ambidextrous adjunction between FinCat and Set.  FinCat, I am defining as the category of all finite categories, with functors as morphisms.  Does such an adjunction exist?  I am most interested in the Frobenius Monad on Set that is generated by this adjunction.  My guess is that there should be "enough" limits and colimits in FinCat for this adjunction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Suppose we have a functor $F\colon \mathsf{(Fin)Set}\to \mathsf{(Fin)Cat}$ which is both a left and a right adjoint (the finiteness in both places is completely optional). Since $F$ is a right adjoint, it preserves limits, and in particular it preserves the terminal object. So $F(1)$ is the category with a single object (and a single arrow, the identity on that object). But since $F$ is a left adjoint, it preserves colimits. And every set is isomorphic to a coproduct of copies of $1$. So $F$ is uniquely determined up to isomorphism: $F(X)$ is a discrete category with $|X|$ objects. (Note that for this to exist at all, the domain has to be $\mathsf{FinSet}$, or the codomain has to be $\mathsf{Cat}$).

This functor $F$ actually happens to have both left and right adjoints (as long as we put in both Fins or neither of them): the left adjoint is the functor which sends a category to its set of connected components, and the right adjoint is the functor which sends a category to its set of objects. But these two functors are not naturally isomorphic, so $F$ is not part of an ambidextrous adjunction.